# warning: cannot find entry symbol _start - while compiling to .so

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, icc

Hello I am running Linux Ubuntu and am compiling using icpc (intel compiler),
I want to get a shared library so I used the command:

```
icpc -o myShared.so -std=c++11 -shared -DSTDC_HEADERS -D __cplusplus=201103L -fpermissive -DPT_XX_DEV -fexceptions -frtti -DANDROID -w -fstack-protector -fPIE -fPIC -pie -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security  -I/home/admins/aaa/include  -I/home/admins/bbb/include a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp  -lpthread -L./../../static_libs -lmyStatic
```

I an getting a warning:

> ```
> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000007040
> ```

I read about this warning in previous topics, and I discovered that this warning connected to the entry point of the program, but as far as I understand - there shouldn't be entry point in shared library.

Does Anyone have an idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `-fPIE` and `-pie` flags solved my problem.
`-pie` shouldn't be used when you are trying to create shared library,
and also `-fPIE` shouldn't be used in most of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

add the following line during compilation. This might solve your problem.

```
-lc --entry main
```

-lc tells the compiler to use the standard C library and --entry main tells the compiler to use the address of 'main' as the application's entry point.

Note: Though I am not familiar with intel compiler still I gave a try.

Comment: There is not main - because what I want to get is Shared Library.

Comment: I use the following options to compile a shared lib.     step 1.   g++ -c  -fpic source_files.cpp -Wall -Wextra -ldl -std=c++0x [ other flags ]
        step2. g++ -shared -o libc.so.6 "all .o file" -Wall -Wextra -ldl -std=c++0x [ other falgs ]

Answer (score 0):

Compile to object files with the Intel compiler, then link the object files using `gcc`.