# gcc -c and ld: exec No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I know this is a very basic question but while I found similar problem I didn't find a solution...

I have the same problem with this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Hi\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

If I compile with gcc main.c, I have no problem.

If I compile with gcc **-c** main.c and then link with **ld -o main main.o**, I obtain the error *undefined reference* for *puts*, *stdout* and *fflush*. I added the **-lc** at the end and the binary file is created with just a warnig on the *_start* point but when I exec the program, it returns a generic **"File not found"** error.
If I'm not wrong the problem is that the linker is using **libc.so.1** that does not exists instead of, I think, **libc.so.6**: with **readelf -a main**

```
[Requesting program interpreter: /usr/lib/libc.so.1]
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? It is some environment/system problem or I have to change the ld options? How?

Thank you and sorry for the "stupid" question... (and for my poor "English")

EDIT: "solved" (see below), just to add the new ld options obtained form **gcc -v main.c** [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS] that I'm trying to reduce at the min:

```
ld -o main main.o --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

EDIT2: to start the program, I think the min is

```
ld -o main main.o --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc
```

It returns a segmentation error (I think for the missed link to crt*)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you let `gcc` call `ld`, that is, what happens if you link using: `gcc -o main main.o` ?

Comment: No, as said if I let gcc call ld I have no problem, sorry I had to highlight it better

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14418246/646887 ?

Comment: Try calling `gcc` on the .o file with the verbose (-v) flag. It will print the command it uses to call `ld`. Check what additional flags it passes to `ld`.

Comment: try to add `-lc --entry main`  
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636471/warning-cannot-find-entry-symbol-start-while-compiling-to-so?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Why are you trying to use `ld` directly?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck actually the answer you linked helped, using the COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS printed with gcc -v in ld, the program works, thank you

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: yes, thank you

Comment: @HmidiSlim Slim: thanks, no, some problem, as said I think the problem is with libc

Comment: @n.m.: I'm not sure but I think I have to use it in a Pro*C project where I first obtained this error

Comment: Pro\*C is a preprocessor, it outputs C source code. It is unclear why you would have to use ld directly in a Pro\*C project.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just link an object file with noting to obtain an executable. You need to link with libraries defining the symbols needed by the object file. Since any C program needs some startup code to initialize `main`'s argc and argv, you likely need to at least link with a file usually called `crt0.o`, probably also with the C standard library.

That's quite involved. If you run a verbose compilation with `gcc -v` you can see the actual link command.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I solved after lookin at gcc -v as suggested also above

Comment: *You can't just link an object file with noting to obtain an executable.* - True for C compiler output, but you *can* do that for an object file built from hand-written asm that defines a `_start`. (Or even a hacky C program that defines a `_start`.)  You link it into a static executable.